# SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file failed - aborted

Tags: openssl, pound

I'm trying to update few of existing SSL certificates with updated expiration on following system:

```
# cat /etc/redhat-release 
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.7 (Santiago)
# uname -a
Linux X 2.6.32-573.3.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Aug 10 09:44:54 EDT 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
# rpm -q Pound openssl
Pound-2.6-2.el6.x86_64
openssl-1.0.1e-42.el6.x86_64
#
```

I have several `Listeners` inside of `pound - HTTP/HTTPS reverse-proxy and load-balancer`, even though both of certificates came from GoDaddy, one of the certificate isn't giving me any issues at all, and the other one does.

I'm getting following error message while issuing `service pound restart`:

> SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file failed - aborted

I'm reading pound_list archive, but as of yet I was not able to find solution that works for me. (My private key is *NOT* password protected).

Comment: Do the two private key files appear to have the same format? Do they look similar in structure?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz format looks same. I just talked to GoDaddy and they agreed to redo them, hopefully everything will work this time.

Comment: GoDaddy generated the private key file?!

Comment: no no) redo certificates. I used `openssl modulus check` and they weren't matching.

Comment: I think private key is ok, it looks like it's mismatching with certificate and that's what cause to generate this error.

Comment: Gotcha. Maybe it's an old private key file? Or maybe it's a new one and the old one was inadvertently used in the request? In any event, a new cert is probably the best way to go, especially if you're not sure what went wrong.

Comment: I used `openssl modulus check | openssl md5` for key, csr and as soon as I get certificates from Godaddy, I will run it against crt as well, they all should match.